# Ruby on Rails Adding comments to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i created a comment controller in rails but if i run the server it gives an error in `db migrate`.

Caused by:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "comments" already exists
C:/Users/SIBI/Desktop/rails1/hello_world/db/migrate/20190516103017_create_comments.rb:3:in `change'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: it seems you already have `comments` table in your database.

Comment: how can i delete that

Comment: if i use "rake db:drop" sqlite is not allowing to drop

Comment: please add create_comment.rb file from migrate folder here.

Comment: already the file is there

Comment: you can go to console and type ```ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:comments)``` to delete the comments if none of the data is needed.

Comment: remove the SQLite DB file in db folder if none of the data is needed

Comment: thank you for all of your suggestions error is cleared